# Liquibase commands are not thread safe even with ThreadLocalScopeManager

Tags: liquibase

I'm running Liquibase commands using Java APIs on multiple databases concurrently with ThreadLocalScopeManager. Noticing that the Liquibase commands are not thread safe. The connection object is being shared across threads leading to connection closed exceptions.

Code Snippet

```
Scope.setScopeManager(new ThreadLocalScopeManager());

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            String dbName = "DB_" + i;
            executor.submit( () -> {
                try(MemoryDatabase db = MemoryDatabase.create(dbName); Connection con = db.getConnection()) {
                    final Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(
                            "com/example/changelog.xml",
                            new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(),
                            new JdbcConnection(con));
                    liquibase.tag("test_started");
                    liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
                    liquibase.tag("test_complete");
                } catch (LiquibaseException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage(), e);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
          });
  }
```

Expecting above code to run liquibase operations on individual databases successfully.

However getting below exception

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID)): The object is already closed [90007-193]
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:235)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$0(Liquibase.java:237)
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:194)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:203)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:193)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:172)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:1605)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:229)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:213)
    at com.example.persistence.dbmigration.ThreadLocalScopeManagerTest.maintainDatabase(ThreadLocalScopeManagerTest.java:89)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID)): The object is already closed [90007-193]
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:337)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:254)
    at liquibase.command.core.helpers.LockServiceCommandStep.run(LockServiceCommandStep.java:37)
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:212)
    ... 15 more
...............
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: The object is already closed [90007-193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1480)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1458)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.createStatement(JdbcConnection.java:202)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:74)
    ... 29 more
```

On basic investigation it looks like an issue with `LockServiceCommandStep` where database is a class member. And looks like multiple threads are using the same `LockServiceCommandStep` object even though we have set `ThreadLocalScopeManager`.

The corresponding test case is ignored in liquibase codebase https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-standard/src/test/groovy/liquibase/ThreadLocalScopeManagerTest.groovy

Is there something else that needs to be done in addition to using `ThreadLocalScopeManager` for running Liquibase with multiple threads?

I am using Liquibase 4.22.0